# Linq: select items in the N side of a 1:N relation

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

i have a table called Text (what's in a name), and a table called TextTranslations

Text can have multiple texttranslations (texttranslation has a FK textid to text.textid)
It also has a property called 'translation'.

Now i have a list of text objects which all have 1 or more texttranslation  child objects.

and i want to match all text objects which have a child (texttranslation) with the 'translation' property equal to something.

so in pseudocode it would be:

list.Where(1 or more z.childs.texttranslation contains 'bla')

is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from text in context.Text
    where text.TextTranslations.Any(tt => tt.Translation.Contains("bla"))
select text;
```

Or

```
context.Text
    .Where(
        text => text.TextTranslations.Any(tt => tt.Translation.Contains("bla")
     );
```

Or

```
(from textTranslation in context.TextTranslations
    where textTranslation.Translation.Contains("bla")
select textTranslation.Text)
.Distinct();
```

Or

```
context.TextTranslations
    .Where(textTranslation => textTranslation.Translation.Contains("bla"))
    .Select(textTranslation => textTranslation.Text)
    .Distinct();
```